# Detecting a browser addon using JavaScript or C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, browser-detection, browser-addons

We are writing a website in C#, and we need to detect if the client's browser has a certain (custom developed) add-on installed.

We have figured out a way how to do it when the client is using Firefox or Internet Explorer. How can we do the same with Safari and Chrome?

Comment: What kind of Platform are you writing?

Comment: Have you figured-out Chrome or not?  You mention it twice in your question.

Comment: I don't agree with those Close votes. This is a real question.

Comment: no i haven't figured out the chrome .. i have added to say .. "firefox and IE".

Comment: @wefx: platform means, a website.

Comment: How do you do it with Firefox and IE?

Comment: add code to display how the plugin detection was achieved for IE and firefox

Comment: Since your detection is actually done in JavaScript (rather than in C#, which just outputs the JavaScript), I've added the javascript tag and changed the title. Hopefully, that will attract JavaScript experts who can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your Addon name to User-Agent variable of your browser (by modyfing this value in browser settings store, open about:config in URL for Firefox). Then you can read it back from `Request` object.

Comment: If the UserAgent string gets too long, it can become truncated and information is lost.

Comment: @Jeff Yates. There is no limitation on HTTP side for that. Do you know any?

Comment: Or (depending on the capabilities of the plugin) add it as a custom (X-*) header.

Comment: Maybe not, but it happens on Windows. I had that issue several times and it caused some weird issues as [ASP.NET truncates the User Agent string to 256 characters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2008/12/29/failure-to-load-report-manager-due-to-truncated-useragent-string.aspx). I wouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

Since addons have permission to modify `DOM`
using the add-on you can inject some javascript variable(e.g. `var IsMyAddonNameInstalled = 'true'`) into the `DOM` when your website is requested from browser
and then pass it to server using `AJAX request` or `hidden input field`.

**PS:** This will work on all browsers